# Field help text is printed as input field title, not in separate field

Tags: 7, entities, bootstrap-theme

On Bootstrap theme add field Text, give it any Help text, save it and you get empty field, but if you hover on the field it shows the help text on mouse tooltip.

But if you e.g. make list field (text) and give it help text, it gets printed in separate `help-block` div under the field. How do I get that for Text fields or all/any fields?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uncheck 'Smart form descriptions (via Tooltips)' in Appearance -> Bootstrap settings -> General -> Forms.
[image]